# Getting error while reading data from Firebase Arduino

Tags: firebase, arduino, nodemcu

I am trying to read the integer values from the Realtime Database of Firebase into Arduino. But when I read it, it always read '0' instead of the integer stored into the database. I have also made the database rules as public in firebase. Below is my code in Arduino. I am using NodeMCU.

```
#include<ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include<FirebaseArduino.h>

#define FIREBASE_HOST "##########"
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "##########"
#define WIFI_SSID "##########"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "##########"

int pin1 = 12;
int pin2 = 14;
int pin3 = 4; 
int pin4 = 5;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(pin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin4, OUTPUT);
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
  Serial.print("connecting");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("connected: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  delay(700);

  Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);
}

void loop() {
  int sw1 = Firebase.getInt("switch1");
  int sw2 = Firebase.getInt("switch2");
  int sw3 = Firebase.getInt("switch3");
  int sw4 = Firebase.getInt("switch4");

  Serial.println(sw1);
  Serial.println(sw2);
  Serial.println(sw3);
  Serial.println(sw4);
  Serial.println("Test");

  if (Firebase.failed()) {
      Serial.print("setting /number failed:");
      Serial.println(Firebase.error());  
      return;
  }
}
```

In the following code, even when I am trying to firebase's error, it is also not printing anything. I am getting the following below output in my serial monitor.

```
connecting:....  
connected: 192.168.1.7
0
0
0
0
Test
setting /number failed:
0
0
0
0
Test
setting /number failed:
```

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a solution for this. I am facing the same issue wherein Firebase.setInt is working perfectly but Firebase.getInt is returning only 1.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem while working with Firebase but I solved the problem. There could be multiple reasons:

1.you should eliminate the `https://` and `/` from your FIREBASE_HOST .Try to run the code see if that works, it works for me.

2.If that did not work you should update your firebase library.